# SQL Server replace string based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, sql-server-2016

I have a string and i would like to replace some words in it by referring a lookup table

```
create table LookupTab 
(
     oldvalue varchar(100),
     newvalue varchar(100)
);

insert into LookupTab 
values ('Run', 'Run Go'), ('Hide', 'Hide Mask'), ('Go', 'Go Run'), ('Mask', 'Mask Hide')
```

Expected output

```
string ='i have to go'     
result ='i have to Go Run'   <-- it should not again replace the word Run

string ='i have to go and go again'     
result ='i have to Go Run and Go Run again'
```

What I have tried

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TranslateString]
    (@Str nvarchar(max))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result nvarchar(max) = @Str;

    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, Oldvalue, NewValue) 
    FROM LookupTab; 

    RETURN @Result;
END
```

but it replaces the replaced word again

Comment: Include what you have tried in your question.

Comment: The strings in your `values()` portion of the `insert` **must be** in single quotes! `insert into LookupTab(oldvalue, newvalue) values ('Run', 'Run Go'), .....`

Comment: Your match is **not** case sensitive `go` and `Go, Go Run`. Is this important?

Comment: @Zhorov its not important.. if we type 'go' it should get replaced with Go Run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=06fd3a2887e1f65344f480a2e2e85de3)

2 steps:

1. Find all the words to replace.
2. Replace with each `@OldValue` to `@NewValue` word accordingly.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TranslateString]
(
 @Str nvarchar(max)
)RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @OldValue nvarchar(100);
  DECLARE @NewValue nvarchar(100);
  DECLARE @CHARINDEX INT = 0;
  DECLARE @Result nvarchar(100) = @Str;
  DECLARE @TempTable AS TABLE(OldValue varchar(100), NewValue varchar(100), isApply BIT) 

  --1. Region: Find all the words to replace
   WHILE (@CHARINDEX < LEN(@Str))
   BEGIN
     SELECT TOP 1 @OldValue = OldValue, @NewValue = newvalue, @CHARINDEX = CHARINDEX(oldvalue, @Str) 
      FROM LookupTab
        WHERE CHARINDEX(oldvalue, @Str) > @CHARINDEX
        ORDER BY CHARINDEX(oldvalue, @Str)

     IF(ISNULL(@OldValue, '') != '' AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @TempTable WHERE OldValue = @OldValue))   
         INSERT INTO @TempTable(OldValue, NewValue)
         VALUES(@OldValue, @NewValue)

     SET @CHARINDEX = @CHARINDEX + LEN(@OldValue);
   END
 --1. End-Region: Find all the words to replace

  --2. Region: Replace with each @OldValue to @NewValue word accordingly
  WHILE(EXISTS(SELECT OldValue FROM @TempTable WHERE ISNULL(isApply, 0) = 0))
  BEGIN
       SELECT @OldValue = OldValue, @NewValue = NewValue FROM @TempTable WHERE ISNULL(isApply, 0) = 0

       SET @Result = replace(@Result,@Oldvalue,@NewValue);
       UPDATE @TempTable SET isApply = 1 WHERE OldValue = @OldValue
  END
  --2. End-Region: Replace with each @OldValue to @NewValue word accordingly

  RETURN @Result;
END
```

*Output*
[image]

**Updated 2020-01-20**

A new solution to fix some exceptional cases. [Demo in db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dceab7a35d9f7a4b1fd02ceff0820fc6)

- Create a `strSplit` function to be able to split each word into a table
- Replace each word by `ISNULL(l.newvalue, s.val)`
- Join all word after replacing into `@Result` then return.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TranslateString]
    (
     @Str nvarchar(max)
    )RETURNS nvarchar(max)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ;WITH cte_TempTable AS(
           select ISNULL(l.newvalue, s.val) AS Value 
           from strSplit(@Str, ' ') s
           left join LookupTab l on s.val = l.oldvalue
        )
        SELECT @Result = (SELECT Value + ' ' FROM cte_TempTable FOR XML PATH(''))

      RETURN @Result;
    END
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Actually it wont. if i type 'i have to go mask' it wont replace the work mask

Comment: To be honest, based on your requirement, it just replace the word "Go" and keep "mask"

Comment: I didnt get you. Actually I should get result like 'i have to Go Run Mask Hide'

Comment: I got it. I just update first word instead all. let me update my answer.

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look. @Surensiveaya

Comment: Oh no.. its failing when i give select [dbo].TranslateString('i have to Go and Go again Run')

Comment: I have given -- order by CHARINDEX(oldvalue, @Str) in first select operation and its working fine. could you please verify and update your answer

Comment: Updated answer @Surensiveaya

Comment: but select [dbo].TranslateString('i have to Go and Go again Run') this gives wrong result.. there is a "Run" at the end

Comment: hmm. It seems to me that there are some exceptional cases like that. I mean The value has been replaced which is duplicate with the new value.

Comment: I think i have. we need to replace each word instead of replacing it all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206259/discussion-between-surensiveaya-and-phong).

Answer (score 1):

This is a challenging problem.  Recursive CTEs can be used to replace the strings.  However, you don't want to replace already replaced strings.  Ouch.

To solve this, you can use two rounds of replacement.  The first puts in a placeholder for the old values.  The second puts in the new values.

This looks like:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), v.str) as str, 1 as lev, str as orig_str
      from (values ('i have to go'), ('i have to Go Run')) v(str)
      union all
      select replace(cte.str, lt.oldvalue, concat('[', lt.ord, ']')), 1 + cte.lev, cte.orig_str
      from cte join
           lookuptab lt
           on lt.ord = cte.lev
     ),
     cte2 as (
      select cte.str, 1 as lev, cte.orig_str
      from (select cte.*, row_number() over (partition by cte.orig_str order by lev desc) as seqnum
            from cte
           ) cte
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select replace(cte2.str, concat('[', lt.ord, ']'), lt.newvalue), 1 + cte2.lev, cte2.orig_str
      from cte2 join
           lookuptab lt
           on lt.ord = cte2.lev
     )
select top (1) with ties str, orig_str
from cte2
order by row_number() over (partition by orig_str order by lev desc);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f8422dd5d6215f02b400ad8d16621669) is a db<>fiddle.

You can add the `ord` column using `row_number()` in a CTE, but I would recommend adding it to the table.

This logic is also easily incorporated into a UDF, if you want that.  I don't recommend a UDF for this purpose.

Comment: Could you please make it as  a function which accept one varchar and replace it as per the requirement

Comment: OP doesn't have `Ord` column.

Comment: @Surensiveaya . . . There is no requirement for a function in the question.  And I don't recommend one either.